# Cannot borrow HashMap as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust

This question was asked zillion times, but it always has kind of unique solution. I understand why it's happening and how to fix it, but my fix is ugly and I'm probably missing something.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut s = Trololo { data: HashMap::new() };
    s.doit();
    s.doit_ugly();
}

struct Trololo {
    data: HashMap<&'static str, String>
}

impl Trololo {
    pub fn doit(&mut self) {
        let a = self.data.get("some key");
        // do something with a
        if a.is_some() {
            // here I don't need 'a' anymore, but because self.data borrowed immutably I can't do anything with it mutably
            self.data.insert("another key", String::new());
        }
    }

    pub fn doit_ugly(&mut self) {
        let mut mutate = false;
        {
            let a = self.data.get("some key");
            // do something with a
            if a.is_some() {
                mutate = true;
            }
        }   // borrow end here, so I can borrow self.data mutably now
        if mutate {
            self.data.insert("another key", String::new());
        }

    }
}
```

The problem here in method `doit()`. I can't borrow `self.data` as mutable because `a` holds a reference to immutably borrowed `self.data`.

It's possible to fix this in `doit_ugly()` method, but it's look terrible.

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: What is your `bool` variable in `doit_ugly()` good for? The `if` condition is always `true` in your code.

Comment: exactly! the only purpose of this boolean is to escape the scope created with `{}` where I can borrow `self.data` immutably and drop it before I can access it mutably

Comment: You do not need it. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e42f1e2cb221d28773b875bb7cb50ab2&version=stable

Comment: See updated post. The point here is not the boolean, but the scope. If I want to call `self.data.insert` based on some condition on `a`, than there is no way to do this without ugly crap like this one with boolean

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `map`:

```
self.data.get("some key")
    .map(|a| println!("{:?}", a)) // do something with a if there is some a
    .map(|_| self.data.insert("another key", String::new()));
```

It maps `a` to `()` enabling `self.data.insert`.

Comment: unfortunately this isn't wotking. neither of map blocks get called https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e42f1e2cb221d28773b875bb7cb50ab2&version=stable

Comment: @OlegAntonyan The map closures get called if  and only if `data` contains "some key".

Comment: sure, but what if it does not contain "some key"? oh, I see. `map`s only help to create closures with separate scopes, so I can still mutate `self.data` outside of them, or inside of each other

Comment: well, it works in this case, but fails if I want to mutate self.data inside first closure https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9f17b052a51f3e4f4d8aecf8c90cd45e&version=stable

Comment: @OlegAntonyan Why would you want to mutate `self.data` in the first closure? Referring to your original code: `// do something with a` goes into the first closure; code within `if mutate { ... }` goes into the second closure.

Comment: this is synthetic example to keep code snippet small. in real project I need to modify a value if it exists in `self.data`, and than insert another value to `self.data`

Comment: @OlegAntonyan In this case, your synthetic example does not represent the actual issue. If `// do something with a` contained code mutating `self.data`, your `doit_ugly` wouldn't compile either.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at [the description for error 502](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0502), I can suggest only one option: place your immutable borrow after the mutable one and use your original data to check the `if` statement instead of `a`:

```
pub fn doit(&mut self) {
    if self.data.get("some key").is_some() {
        self.data.insert("another key", String::new());
    }

    let a = self.data.get("some key");
}
```